# Change Dollars with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

in Itunes $0.99 == Rp9500

I want to show like these:

for US region: $0.99
 and for Indonesia region Rp9500

how to convert USD to IDR?

here is my code.

```
NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[priceFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:@(0.99)]
```

the result from code above are:

for US region $0.99

and

for Indonesia region Rp 1 (I don't understand, why it is become 1 and not 9500)

thank you very much, I'm sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumberFormetter` does exactly what it's name implies - given a number it *formats* (produces a textual representation of it). The class does not *convert* numbers between different units, two currencies in your case. To do the conversion you need to look up the conversion rate and do the multiplication yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The formatter doesn't calculate based on exchange rates. So its taking 0.99 as Rp, you don't appear to have decimal places so it rounds it up to the nearest digit.

You'll need to convert the value of 0.99 based on an exchange rate.

If this value is coming from the app store as an IAP then the conversion will already happen for you

[SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008414%5D)

Comment: hi, thanks for your response

I followed a tutorial, and the author finally answer it's only work for In-app purchases.

now I see, why it doesn't work.

I'm sorry for this stupid question